# Why isn't 'ich' capitalized in German?

Tags: capitalization

I am quite surprised to see the sentence,

> Hallo, ich bin Kellner.

Contrary to English I, 'ich' was not capitalized.
What is the reason that the German ich is not capitalized?
(In other words, why is the English I is capitalized?)

Comment: Why should *ich* be capitalized? The real question here is the one in brackets and that's not just *in other words*. It's a different question and unfortunately off topic here.

Comment: VTR. The question "Why isn't 'ich' capitalized in German?" may be seen as showing little research effort *about the English "I"*, but it's a completely valid question from someone in whose language it is capitalized. I disagree that the real question here is the one in brackets. You only know that if you know the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Answers to the question about English "I" can be found [here on English Language SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/why-should-the-first-person-pronoun-i-always-be-capitalized.).

According to that, capitalized "I" originated in the 13th century because *i* is a very small letter that was hard to discern as a word in the writing style that was used in that period. So the *i* was written a bit larger, which was later continued as a capitalized *I*.

The word "ich" doesn't have that problem, and all other pronouns in German are not capitalized either (with some exceptions to honor a person or deity, like polite "Sie", polite "Du", or when writing about god), so it seems logical to not capitalize "ich".

Comment: Except for *Sie*, the polite form of "you". I suppose one reason is to help avoid confusion with the other *sie* pronouns, though you can often tell them apart by the way the verb is conjugated. Maybe a better question is why isn't there a capitalized form of "You"; maybe "you" for singular and "You" for plural. Seems like that would make things clearer.

Comment: @RDBury There actually _are_ capitalized forms of the second person pronouns. Generally, "du", "dein", "ihr", "euer" etc. aren't capitalized. But when the speaker is directly adressing somebody, for example in a letter, you can write "Liebe Oma, ich hoffe, es geht Dir gut". The lowercase version is acceptable here, too, but at least to me it seems a bit less polite than the capitalized version. See for example [duden.de](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Gross-oder-Kleinschreibung-von-duDu-und-ihrIhr).